# Should a function accept/return values in (row,col) or (col,row) order?

Tags: c#, python, c++, conventions

Say I have a function that accepts a row and a column as parameters, or returns a tuple of a row and a column as its return value. I know it doesn't actually make a difference, but is there a convention as to whether put the row first or the column first? Coming from math, if I think of the pair as coordinates into the table, I would intuitively put the column first, as in a cartesian point (x,y). But if I think of it as a whole matrix, I would put row first, as in MxN size of a matrix.

If there are different conventions for different languages, I would be interested especially in c++, c# and python.
By "convention" I mean preferably that that language's standard library does it a certain way, and if not that then second choice would be only if it were so universal that all major third-party libraries for that language would do it that way,preferably with an explanation why.

Comment: in python, R, and Matlab usually row then col

Comment: While trying to avoid the "it depends" answer, the answer is most likely "it depends."  As you have highlighted in your question, there are times when one is acceptable over the other depending on the application.  As a point of preference, I typically will default to M,N (row,column) unless the application I am applying the variables to dictates otherwise.  This ensures consistency between variable declaration and standard Python practices (for example, Tuples represented as row,column).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in c# the default enumerator for a 2D-array will yield items in column then row order ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BERs6Z)).

Comment: @JohnWu No, it doesn't. It yields them in order, iterating each inner array before iterating to the next one in the outer. You just decided arbitrarily to assign a meaning of column to the inner level and row to the outer one.

Comment: @Baruch A strange comment. There are no "inner" or "outer" anything in my example. If you're referring to my decision to put `x` before `y` when indexing into a two-dimensional array, that is hardly arbitrary.

Comment: @JohnWu In line #9 in your fiddle, you initialize the 2d array with an array of arrays. That is what I am referring to as "outer" (the array containing arrays) and "inner" (the  arrays contained in the array). I don't see any `x` or `y` in your code, but how is deciding to put `x` before `y` not arbitrary?

Comment: I would think that asking for conventions based off a language's standard library is not "opinion based"

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of what is "horizontal" and what is "vertical". You should think of which convention is widely used not to introduce a lot of surprise to the developers who would use your code. The same is true for naming the parameters: use `(x, y, z)` for coordinates, `(i, j)` for indexes in matrix and `(row, column)` for the cells of the table (in this order).

I agree with @ParalysisByAnalysis that sometimes it depends, but the rule of thumb is to follow the conventions of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to address (column, row) like (x, y).

Column refers to the type of value and row indicates the value for the column.

Column is a key and with Row you have the value.

But using (row, column) is fine too.

It depends of what you're doing.

In SQL/Linq, you always refers to Columns to get rows.

Comment: Column typically does **not** refer to the type of value.

Comment: @martineau I'am sorry, but columns define the type of the values of items of rows. Things are done like that with the Database Theory and with SQL. So, data are arranged by columns that define types of properties and rows that contain values or instances. It is an universal convention, not an opinion.

Comment: No, it is a universal convention only when applied to data sets. But what if it is a tiled map, or the multiplication table, or some other form of lookup table, or one of many other uses for 2d data structures?